# R Markdown / knitr with sql engine - error when creating new table in Oracle database

Tags: sql, r, oracle, knitr, r-markdown

I am writing a R Markdown file with a sequence of sql chunks. Each chunk contains a `CREATE TABLE` statement that writes data into an Oracle database. For instance:

````
```{r setup}
library(knitr)
library(ROracle)
con <- dbConnect(dbDriver("Oracle"), ...)
```

```{sql, connection = "con"}    
CREATE TABLE TEST AS SELECT * FROM TESTTABLE
```
````

Ideally, I would like to get a report that contains the SQLs followed by messages of success or failure. However, when I run the chunks, tables are successfully created, but the following error messages appear:

> Error in seq_len(ncol(data)) :    argument must be coercible to
>   non-negative integer In addition: Warning message: In
>   seq_len(ncol(data)) : first element used of 'length.out' argument

This suggests to me that the result of the SQL statement (which is a logical TRUE or FALSE) cannot be transformed and displayed correctly. A workaround is to assign the result of the SQL to R via the `output.var` option and then print it in a separate R chunk.

````
```{sql, connection = "con", output.var = "createTableResult"}    
CREATE TABLE TEST AS
SELECT * FROM TESTTABLE
```

```{r}
createTableResult
```

[1] TRUE
````

Is there a way to avoid this workaround? 
Can I somehow get the resulting TRUE or FALSE message directly from the SQL chunk?